# How to limit the user to practice only single session in one browser window in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

We developing web application using MVC4 and Jquery Mobile. Recently we found one major issue which is "User using another account in same browser" so its overiding the existing account current browser. So we decided not to allow user to use two different account in one browser. We searched lot but unable to find perfect solution. So we tryed below code before login page load.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return View("mLogin");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("UserAlready");

             }
        }
```

In login controller we written this code. The login page will be shown only when user is not registered. Once he Authenticated we restrict him from loading login page again.

My question.

Is this correct method ? Is it have any drawback? Or any other better approach is there?

Comment: Wouldn't be a filter better solution? Filter could handle every action and chceck that condition - you wouldn't have to take care of it in eveery action manually.

Comment: @pwas: no filter in FilterConfig.js cant do the job.i need to check only in login controller index action method. so the above code is fullfill my job.

Comment: you are doing right. go with it

Answer (score 0):

Use a cookie with session id in it. In Authorize Action Filter check cookie for the session value with user session value if two match well and good otherwise you can take the necessary action